# How to freeze table header at modal box

Tags: php, modal-dialog, table-lock

So I have tried using these [TableLock](https://github.com/kjellericson/TableLock) method on [normal page](http://imgur.com/A0SgSk0), it [works just fine](http://imgur.com/01p6toB), but I tried using it on [modal box](http://imgur.com/aG4cN1x) and [it didn't work](http://imgur.com/siWaVyz). Any idea how to make table header at modal box freezes after it touched the top part of browser? I don't want the whole table to stay in one place like this [freeze pane](http://imgur.com/BRJ86lI).